# Anyone upgraded Turbopower's Onguard to Delphi-2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, onguard

Titel says it all: has anyone been able to upgrade The Onguard component suite from Turbopower (which is opensource) to Delphi-2010 ?

I am still trying to make sure all my trusted components (which I have used for years in Delphi 7) can be compiled and used in Delphi-2010.

Not an easy tasks at all.

I would pay any reasonable price for anyone wanting to help me in this convertions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at [this](http://www.songbeamer.com/delphi/)

Comment: This is soo cool. I am downloading the Turbopopwer components as I type this. If this work, you saved me a lot of time.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You should use the SourceForge version.  That is the "official" repository for the code and the place that updates will  be done.

Comment: I did. But the latest version 1.14 has been committed only yesterday. I must have checked SourceForge only hours before this. Thx

Comment: Version 1.14 at SourceForge does not compile under Delphi-2010.

Comment: In contrast to my previous comment: the one I downloaded from the link mentioned in this answer, does compile under Delphi-2010. Havent't tested it yet, though.

Answer (score 2):

Just a few days ago Roman Kassebaum committed an updated version 1.14 to the sourceforge repository, which supports D2009/D2010 and Unicode.

Take a look at [OnGuard 1.14 at Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tponguard/files/tponguard/1.14/tponguard_1_14.zip/download).

Comment: I did check SourceForge yesterday morning and found the last source to be from 2003.

The 1.14 version must have been committed after I checked.

Of course I will use the 'official' version. Thanks.

Comment: Version 1.14 at SourceForge does not compile under Delphi-2010. So for Delphi-2010 this is a useless update. Did a search on 1.14 in all .pas files and found nothing. So either nothing changed, or the author forgot to update the version number in the source files.